# SQL problems i need help fast

Tags: sql

If i don't put a '**WHERE**' in front of type i get an error for 'type'

```
string sql = "UPDATE Resource SET " + "location='" + location + "'" + "WHERE levelNo='" + levelNo + "'" + "Type='" + type + "'" + " Abr='"+ abr + "'" + " Description='" + description + "'" + " Capacity='" +capacity +"'" + " Detail='" + detail + "'";
```

but if i put it i get the error for '**WHERE**'

```
string sql = "UPDATE Resource SET " + "location='" + location + "'" + "WHERE levelNo='" + levelNo + "'" + "**WHERE** Type='" + type + "'" + " Abr='"+ abr + "'" + " Description='" + description + "'" + " Capacity='" +capacity +"'" + " Detail='" + detail + "'";
```

Comment: First of all, it's easier to read if you just provide the SQL, since that's the issue.  Second of all, you probably want some `AND`s in there.

Comment: Missing a space before WHERE.

Comment: You should include what you're trying to do for context and provide the error messages that you're getting.

Answer (score 4):

You need `AND`s between your additional conditions, not additional `WHERE` clauses

Answer (score 2):

"WHERE levelNo='" + levelNo + "' **AND** " + "Type='" + type + "'"